# Android - Custom Font Button - color specified in style not being set

Tags: android, android-studio

I have created a MyButton class to set and display a custom
`public class MyButton extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton {

```
public MyButton(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

    init();
}

private void init(){
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Filmcryptic.ttf");
    setTypeface(tf);

}
```

}
`

In my styles.xml file, I have set a style like this, where I only want to override the textcolor and the size -

```
    <style name="taWhiteButtonText" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FF0000</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20dp</item>
</style>
```

In my layout file, I am using it so -

```
<com.xx.yyy.MyButton
    android:id="@+id/button_start_quiz"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@drawable/chalkbutton"
    android:text="Start Quiz"
    style="@style/taWhiteButtonText"
    />
```

The problem I face is that the font size changes as I update the style, but the font color does not get reflected.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Change your parent in style.xml file.

```
    <style name="taWhiteButtonText" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FF0000</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I tried this, but still not working : its not setting bold style : <style name="taWhiteButtonText" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
        <item name="android:textColor">#FF0000</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">20dp</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/custom_fonts</item>
        <item name="fontFamily">@font/custom_fonts</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    </style>